# Actions not dispatching

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

When I run an action creator to create my thunk, it does not run the dispatch functions.

For testing, I put a button in my root component's render method, my root component is connected thusly (removed extraneous things):

```
import { loadAndSetCurrentUser } from '../Actions/SedFF';
import { setSysMenuExpand, setNavMenuExpand, setLoginDialogVisibility } from '../Actions/UI';

render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={() => 
            loadAndSetCurrentUser("username@email.com")}>LASCU</button>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
    return {
        UI: state.UI,
        sedff: state.SedFF,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    loadAndSetCurrentUser,
}


export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WebFF)));
```

My Actions Creators file looks like this:

```
export function loadAndSetCurrentUser(username) {
    console.log("LASCU: " + username);
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        console.log("in dispatch");
        dispatch(this.requestingUserData(username)); 

        const user = getState().Users[username];
        if (user) {
            // if already in store, just change the current username  
            //FUTURE: check date against user mod date in database
            dispatch(setCurrentUsername(username));
            dispatch(userDataLoadComplete());
        } else {
            // user not in store, need to check database //TODO:
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?username=Bret')
                .then(response => response.json())
                // .then(json => delay(3000, json))
                .then(json=> dispatch(ingestUserData(json)))
                .then(() => dispatch(userDataLoadComplete()));
        }
    }
}

export function requestingUserData(username) {
    console.log("RUD");
    return { type: REQUESTING_USER_DATA, username };
}

export function setCurrentUsername(username) {
    return { type: SET_CURRENT_USERNAME, username }
}

export function ingestUserData(userData) {
    return (dispatch) =>
        {
            console.log("IUD");
            console.log(userData);
            dispatch({ type: SET_USER_DATA, userData })
        }
}

export function userDataLoadComplete() {
    return { type: USER_DATA_LOAD_COMPLETE };
}
```

And my reducers are bone-stock, looking like this:

```
export function SedFF(state = initialSedFFState, action) {
    let newState = _.cloneDeep(state);
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_CURRENT_USERNAME:
            newState.currentUsername = action.username
            return newState;
        case LOAD_USER_DATA:
            //TODO: 
             return newState;
        case REQUESTING_USER_DATA:
            newState.isFetchingUserData = true;
            return newState;
        case RECEIVED_USER_DATA:
            //TODO:
            newState.isFetchingUserData = false;
            return newState
        case USER_DATA_LOAD_COMPLETE:
            //TODO:
            newState.isFetchingUserData = false;
            return newState

... etc, etc...

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

When I hit the LASCU button, I get the following output:  `LASCU: username@email.com` coming from my action creator (noted on the second line of the action creator file above).  I do NOT get the `in dispatch` output on the 4th line of my action creator file. I do NOT get any actions firing.

I'm unsure why the dispatch is not firing.

I will note that on a different component (a sub-component), I can get it to fire the entire thing, but I'm unable to find any differences.  The only real difference appear to be that I don't have the router in the export line:
`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(SystemMenu));`

For what it's worth, my thunk middleware is connected at the App.js (parent of my root component) like so:

```
const store = createStore(
    RootReducer, 
    initialState, 
    composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <WebFF />
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}


export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(App);
```

Thoughts?  Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the render method given in the question, the issue appears to be that you're calling the *original imported function*, not the *bound function from props*. In other words, changing to `this.props.loadAndSetCurrentUser()` should work correctly. Note that [you shouldn't be importing the store directly into a component file](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself).

For more details, please see the React-Redux [usage guide docs page on "Dispatching Actions with `mapDispatch`"](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch).

Answer (score 0):

You still have to **dispatch** the Thunk action, otherwise it will just return the action and not do anything with it.

```
render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={() => 
            store.dispatch(loadAndSetCurrentUser("username@email.com"))
        }>LASCU</button>
    )
}
```

So, basically what you were doing was similar to:

```js
const action = function (username) { return function () { alert(username); }}
console.log(action('123')); // This will just log `function () { alert(username); }`, without actually running the alert()
```

So, even though you call `action('123')`, it will just return a function that still has to be called somehow. In the case of Thunks, the returned function has to be dispatched.

Comment: You're close, but slightly off.  Looking at the render method given in the question, the issue appears to be that the OP is calling the _original imported function_, not the _bound function from props_.  In other words, changing to `this.props.loadAndSetCurrentUser()` should work correctly.  Note that [you shouldn't be importing the store directly into a component file](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself).

Comment: Cristy: I don't have direct access to the store, in general.
@markerikson:  You are absolutely correct.  I made your change and it worked.  Make this into an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @markerikson Wait, so if you use the mapped/bound function, it will automatically dispatch the action after the constructor is called? (my solution probably still works, but it's not a recommended practice, I actually have used it in production for a long time and had no issues with it, having a singleton store)

Comment: Yes.  All I did was add "this.props." in front of my call and it works.  This makes sense, as now it's going through the functions passed with mapDispatchToProps instead of calling the function directly from the import (As I was erroneously doing).

You are right, I think your solution would have also worked.

Comment: @Cristy : yes, that's the entire point of `mapDispatchToProps` :)  For more details, please see the React-Redux [usage guide docs page on "Dispatching Actions with `mapDispatch`"](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch).